# .NET Linq MD5 (From Column)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, edmx

How i convert this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Test Where md5(field) = 'my_hash'
```

To LINQ?

Note: 
I can't use the method (external) inside linq expression (throws) 
then i can't apply a md5 method in field.

Note 2: 
I already have the md5 method

Comment: Normally the database would store the already-hashed data... is that really not the case here?

Comment: linq and entity framework have no equivilant.

Comment: Just stating the obvious - you can always do a regular SQL query rather than LinqToSQL.

Comment: I can't manage the db in this scenario (linqtosql it's a option) thnks

Comment: I meant do an SQL query from C#.

Comment: What is `md5` in this case? A SQL function or a .NET method?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your complete scenario, but in most cases it's better to store the hashed field value itself (possibly in another column) than compute it at SQL runtime. It has a better performance, and in that way you can simply create the corresponding LINQ query.